# Get Processing abandoned The video could not be processed error after use curl in google colab

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, upload, google-colaboratory, access-token

I uploaded my video with mp4 format to Google Colab disk storage. then replaced with Google Console access token and run following curl command in a cell:

```
!curl -X POST -i "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2Cstatus" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
  -d "{\"snippet\":{\"categoryId\":\"22\",\"description\":\"Description of uploaded video.\",\"title\":\"Test video upload.\"},\"status\":{\"privacyStatus\":\"private\"}}"
```

after run this command i got location url and replace with path of my video in google colab in following curl command and run successfuly following command:

```
!curl -X PUT -i 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet%2Cstatus&upload_id=###' \
-F "media=@/path/to/video.mp4"
```

But after successfully executing the above two commands, I encounter the following scene on my YouTube channel. What is the problem?

[image]
I tested the above commands with videos of different sizes but the problem still persists. I even tested the instructions with a 3 MB video. The problem is not the size of the videos!
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Is there any specific information to your upload if you click the "Learn More" link? Update your question with that info (please don't reply in comments). ... For future reference this isn't  really a programming question. Better to  post such Qs to [su]. AND generally, posting images is an indication that you're posting to the wrong forum. We want to see `if-then-else` program code, but as you have several steps of `curl` "code", I'm not voting to close. (Don't have the time to edit this into something less rambling, Sorry). Good luck.